# Can Technomancer progress two arcane casting classes at once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, prestige-class

So I am planning out my character for the next AP my group is doing. We decided upon "Iron Gods" so naturally I want to make a [Technomancer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/s-z/technomancer). So looking around I found the "[Spell Slinger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo---wizard-archetypes/spellslinger)" Wizard archetype. Well after reading some info I will be dipping 1 level into [Crossblooded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo---sorcerer-archetypes/crossblooded) Sorceror, with Djinni and Draconic line for the awesome electric damage.

The thing is Technomancer at level 2 and beyond says "+1 level of arcane spell casting" does this apply to the Sorcerer **and** Wizard levels, just the Wizard, or just the Sorcerer? Me and my buddy aren't sure and I am not finding the info I need.

I ask because some others say "+1 level of existing arcane spell casting" but the Technomancer wording is different.

Comment: Technomancer appears to be poorly written, not following standard templating for prestige classes; it's mostly likely that it should read exactly like other PrCs that give spellcasting progression.

Comment: Ok thanks. I figured as much but I was just verifying because sometimes things like that aren't a mistake. :) Thanks!

Comment: I'll do research tomorrow and get you an official answer If no  one beats me to it.   If I do, I'll work in a rant about poorly written classes :)

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but I'm pretty sure if technomancer advanced multiple versions of spellcasting simultaneously, that'd be, technically, *more* than *+1 level of arcane spellcasting*. That is, plus one level to *this* class's arcane spellcasting **and** plus one level to *that* class's arcane spellcasting is, after all, more than *just* plus one level of arcane spellcasting. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 7):

The technomancer is a deficient prestige class: the table is **not** enough to go on, and it lacks any actual textual description of its spellcasting advancement. That means, fundamentally, that we cannot answer the question in any sure or official capacity; official sources failed to provide an answer.

As a DM, personally I would look *very* poorly at a prestige class that made such a basic mistake (and at a company that published it). It implies a distinct lack of familiarity with how prestige classes work on the part of the author, and considerable negligence on the part of the editor. These things make me suspicious that there are problems with the class as a whole; to approve it, I would feel the need to vet the entire class myself, treating it just as I would homebrew; the “official” stamp does not appear to be very valuable here.

That said, prestige class spellcasting advancement does *usually* follow a standard pattern; most prestige classes just copy and paste the standard blurb, with the appropriate blanks filled in by the prestige class’s name. That blurb, for example from arcane trickster, is as follows:

> When a new arcane trickster level is gained, the character gains new spells per day as if she had also gained a level in a spellcasting class she belonged to before adding the prestige class. She does not, however, gain other benefits a character of that class would have gained, except for additional spells per day, spells known (if she is a spontaneous spellcaster), and an increased effective level of spellcasting. **If a character had more than one spellcasting class before becoming an arcane trickster, she must decide to which class she adds the new level for purposes of determining spells per day.**

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

Presumably technomancer was intended to follow this same standard, and therefore cannot advance two spellcasting classes. Note that mystic theurge, a class that **does** advance two spellcasting classes, is quite explicit about it: each level lists a Spells per Day of “+1 level of existing arcane spellcasting class/+1 level of existing divine spellcasting class,” and the textual description is:

> When a new mystic theurge level is gained, the character gains new spells per day as if he had also gained a level in any one arcane spellcasting class he belonged to before he added the prestige class and any one divine spellcasting class he belonged to previously. He does not, however, gain other benefits a character of that class would have gained. This essentially means that he adds the level of mystic theurge to the level of whatever other arcane spellcasting class and divine spellcasting class the character has, then determines spells per day, spells known, and caster level accordingly. **If a character had more than one arcane spellcasting class or more than one divine spellcasting class before he became a mystic theurge, he must decide to which class he adds each level of mystic theurge for the purpose of determining spells per day.**

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

Here, advancing two classes is explicitly described, and the mystic theurge even includes a sentence that mimics the arcane trickster’s about having multiple qualifying classes.

So, even though the technomancer is poorly written and incomplete, and we can’t say *for sure*, the answer to your question is still *almost certainly* “no.”

Comment: Even if it does progress "arcance spellcasting" rather than the normal PrC thing, what that means would need to be defined.  Its possible to enter this class without even being a member of an arcane spellcasting class (e.g. via spell-capturing gems), and it appears that the table would raise your arcane spellcasting in that case anyways.